# Reading OSX disk from Ubuntu: Permission Denied

Tags: mount, permissions, macosx

I have an OSX and Ubuntu dual-boot system. In Ubuntu, I would like to be able to mount and read the OSX partition.

It is currently mounted in `/media` (this seems to have been done automatically). However, I do not have permission to explore `~/Documents` on the OSX drive. What can I do to give myself this permission? Presumably I need to somehow ´log in' to the drive with my OSX user-id and password.

(Ultimately, I would like to do something similar to the configure Linux section in [this tutorial](http://docs.cslabs.clarkson.edu/wiki/Dual_Boot_OS_X_and_Ubuntu).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://mac.linux.be/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=95) is the tutorial I follow every time I install ubuntu on a macbook. Basically the user ID of Mac and Ubuntu are different so you get permission errors when you try and browse a users home folder (it's a security feature). This tutorial will show you how to set Ubuntu's user and group ID's to match the Mac ones. If you have any questions just let me know, I've done this many times.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer on this, it seems to be what I want, but I´ve had some issues. I´ve followed the instructions carefully, and the current situation is that when I log in as my main account, I get immediately logged back out again (I am still able to log in as ´temp´). The login screen gives no indication of the account being logged in (i.e. no white arrow by my name), but on the other hand in the ´switch user´ menu in temp I have a tick mark by my name. Do you have any advice for what I might be able to do to resolve this? (All on 11.10). Thanks.

Comment: It would seem like you may have neglected the step "Change the file permissions of our original account’s home folder to correspond with the changes to our user and group ID." ; apologies if this is not the case. Solution ; log in at tty1 - press <kbd>ctrl+alt+F1</kbd>, log in with your user account, and `cd /home` ; then `chown -R user:user user` where "user" is your user name.

Comment: It turns out I had done that, but the file permissions were messed up; my root user didn´t have write permissions on the home directory any more (I fixed with chmod). I additionally had to go back again because my OSX user ID was 502 not 501; but now it all seems to be working, touch wood! Thanks for the help both.

Comment: No problem! Sorry you had some rough spots, but I'm glad it's working now.